# Android Studio, Al llamar otro activity y realizar consulta de SQL tarda en cargar

Tags: android, sql, android-studio

Buen dia.

Soy nuevo en android studio y tengo un código que dejo el programador anterior en la empresa de una aplicación interna la cual consulta una base de datos.

El problema que presento es que al momento de ingresar a la aplicación y dar clic al botón "iniciar sesión" para hacer login, tarda aproximadamente 6 segundos en cargar y mostrar el próximo Layout.

```
introducir el código aquí  private void InicioSesion() {
    try{
        if (!edtUsuario.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
            PreparedStatement search;
            search = conexiónDB().prepareStatement("select Name, U_zona, U_password, U_tipo_usuario from usuario where usuario = '"+edtUsuario.getText()+"' and contrasena = '"+edtContraseña.getText() +"'");
            ResultSet resultSet = search.executeQuery();
            if (resultSet.next()) {
                if(resultSet.getString("U_tipo_usuario").equals("Comercial")) {
                    Intent menuprincipal = new Intent(UsuarioLogin.this, MenuPrincipal.class);
                    menuprincipal.putExtra("serie", resultSet.getString("U_zona"));
                    menuprincipal.putExtra("name", resultSet.getString("Name"));
                    startActivity(menuprincipal);
                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Este usuario no tiene acceso a esta aplicacion", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Usuario o Contraseña invalidos", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Ingrese usuario y contraseña", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    } catch (Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Que tarde más o menos puede depender de muchos factores, como la velocidad de conexión, el servidor utilizado, etc... De todas maneras, sería interesante que pusieras si utilizas alguna librería para realizar esta conexión. Te comento esto último porque yo tuve un problema similar (conexión muy lenta) y me tuve que pasar a la librería Volley (https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html) para realizar las conexiones con los webservices y se solucionó.

Comment: como dice el compañero el que tarde depende de varios factores, al ser desde un celular que haces la consulta directamente a la base de datos la unica es que tengas una mala conexion, yo la verdad te sugiero usar apis para este tipo de consulta. que algun back se conecte a la bd.